# WPF - DataGrid column binding to attached property not working on context menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, contextmenu, attached-properties

I have `ToggleButton`s and a `DataGrid`, each row in `DataGridColumn` has a `ColGroup` `AttachedProperty` set to the name of the column group name.

Attached property:

```
public class DataGridColumnsGroupProperty {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColGroupProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColGroup", typeof(object), typeof(DataGridColumnsGroupProperty), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void SetColGroup(DependencyObject element, string value) {
        element.SetValue(ColGroupProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetColGroup(DependencyObject element) {
        return (string)element.GetValue(ColGroupProperty);
    }
}
```

The `ToggleButton`s has two jobs, on `Check/UnCheck` `show/collapse` all columns with the same group name.

and it has a `ContextMenu` which shows only the `DataGridColumns` with the same group name.

I've managed to bind all `DataGridColumns` to the `ToggleButton`, but couldn't find a way to Collapse the `DataGridColumns` with different group names.

How to fill context menu with only the columns with the givin group name inside the Style Trigger?

And how to hid all columns that has the group name when un-check toggle button?

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Columns, ElementName=ElementDataGrid, Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{Binding HeaderTemplate}"/>
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Visibility, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToBooleanConverter}}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="attachedProperties:DataGridColumnsGroupProperty.ColGroup" Value="FirstGroup">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
</ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
```

DataGridColumns:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StoryCol" attachedProperties:DataGridColumnsGroupProperty.ColGroup="FirstGroup" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Story}" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Story}" Visibility="Visible" />
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CadIdCol" attachedProperties:DataGridColumnsGroupProperty.ColGroup="SecondGroup" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.CadId}" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding CadId}" Visibility="Visible" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `DataTrigger` should work as far as the binding to the attached property is concerned:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(attachedProperties:DataGridColumnsGroupProperty.ColGroup)}" Value="FirstGroup">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. is there a way to hide any column that has the ColGroup value the same as the ToggleButton, without code behind checking for check un-check for toggle button?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you are asking. What does the "the same as the ToggleButton..." mean?

Comment: I have the property ColGroup set to all DataGridColumns with different values, like 'firstGroup' 'secondGroup'. When check a toggle button, I need to hide all DataGridColumns with one specific value like hiding all the columns that has the ColGroup value set to 'firstGroup'.

Comment: Isn't that what your trigger is doing?

Comment: Ok, so the trigger is binding all the columns with a specific value, to the ToggleButton's ContextMenu.

What I'm looking for is to hide the columns inside the DataGrid which have this specific value when un-check the toggle button.

I feel I'm missing something here, I could do this in code behind, but a cleaner Xaml code is more convenient.

Comment: I don't think I agree. XAML is a *markup* language and while you may *can* do something in XAML, it doesn't mean that you always should. Doing to much in XAML is generally considered as an antipattern and may lead to an unmaintainable mess :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll take it into the consideration next time, and I will fix this in code behind then. :)